# How to return correct sum from s subselect?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum, subquery

I have a subselect which is part of a bigger select. I want to SUM all weights for one order and display that sum, but constantly get errors or multiple returned values:

```
SELECT "Invoice Date", "Invoice Number", "Invoice Currency Code",    
(select sum(items.GEWICHTF) from consignment left join items on items.consid=consignment.id group by consignment.orderNo)) "Weight", 
    
FROM order
LEFT JOIN partner ON order.customer=partner.nr
LEFT JOIN consignment ON order.nr=consignment.orderno
LEFT JOIN items ON items.consid=consignment.id
LEFT JOIN transportorder ON consignment.consid=transportorder.consid

WHERE partner.nr=26601102;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you really need the subquery - is there a reason that you can't just sum the weights and group by the other columns all in the main query?

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sum-analytic-function about half way down.

Comment: The subquery needs to be correlated, and without GROUP BY.

Comment: Comment 1: I can't because the whole main query is bigger than what is here. It has at least 10 more columns and 5 more JOINed tables. It would be impossible to group the whole query.

Comment 3: I have no idea what you mean and how to do it.

Comment: Comment 2: I've read and searched but cannot find a suitable way to implement it in my qyuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you don't know what a correlated subquery is, then (read comments within code):

```
SELECT "Invoice Date",
       "Invoice Number",
       "Invoice Currency Code",
       --
       -- this is a correlated subquery; it puts ITEMS table to relation with ...
       (SELECT SUM (items.gewichtf)
          FROM items 
         WHERE items.consid = consignment.id) "Weight"
  FROM t_order
       LEFT JOIN partner ON order.customer = partner.nr
       LEFT JOIN consignment ON order.nr = consignment.orderno  --> ... the CONSIGNMENT table
       LEFT JOIN items ON items.consid = consignment.id
       LEFT JOIN transportorder ON consignment.consid = transportorder.consid
 WHERE partner.nr = 26601102;
```

I understand, you posted just a small piece of code you really have so this may, or may not work.

---

To comment your comment about what Alex commented:

> It would be impossible to group the whole query.

Impossible? On the other hand, it would be possible - it would just require some more typing, to specify all non-aggregated columns into the `group by` clause.

Would it work properly? I have no idea, it depends on what you want.

Option which *would* work is to create a **function** that calculates the result and then call that function from your query, directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_weight (par_id IN items.consid%TYPE)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   retval  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM (i.gewichtf)
     INTO retval
     FROM items i
    WHERE i.consid = par_id;

   RETURN retval;
END;
/

SELECT "Invoice Date",
       "Invoice Number",
       "Invoice Currency Code",
       --
       f_weight (consignemnt.id) "Weight"               --> here
  FROM t_order
       LEFT JOIN partner ON order.customer = partner.nr
```

Doing so, you wouldn't need a `GROUP BY` at all (unless there are other aggregates there).

Drawback? Context switching; might (and will) slow things down. For small data set, you won't notice the different. For large data set, you most probably will.

---

Finally, just a comment: this is Oracle, and we usually *hate* enclosing anything into double quotes and put spaces in between words. Let the front end care about labels. I'd suggest you to

```
select invoice_date, invoice_currency_code, weight from ...
```

and then (as I said) use any label you want *in front end*.

Answer (score 0):

If all the rows are in your outer query (without duplicates) then you you can use the `SUM` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT "Invoice Date",
       "Invoice Number",
       "Invoice Currency Code",
       SUM(items.GEWICHTF) OVER (PARTITION BY consignment.orderNo) AS "Weight"
FROM   order
       LEFT JOIN partner ON order.customer=partner.nr
       LEFT JOIN consignment ON order.nr=consignment.orderno
       LEFT JOIN items ON items.consid=consignment.id
       LEFT JOIN transportorder ON consignment.consid=transportorder.consid
WHERE  partner.nr=26601102;
```